# Optimize filesize of Blazor WASM application

Tags: .net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I'm building a Blazor WASM application that should be able to be used on sometimes slow internet connections. I'm trying to optimize the initial download size but I'm running into some issues.

- .NET 7
- Blazor WASM
- Authentication through OpenIdConnect
- Using nuget packages:

  - Telerik
  - Blazored.Modal
  - Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization
  - Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly
  - Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication
  - Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization.DevServer
  - Microsoft.Extensions.Http
  - Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Configuration
  - Some self build Nuget packages which only include .razor, .css, .cs... files (do I need to activate some sort of trimming on these?)

The size of published files (with `dotnet publish -c release`) is 22mb.
[image]

I have tried the following:

- Adding the following lines to my .csproj

  ```
   <PropertyGroup>
   <InvariantGlobalization>true</InvariantGlobalization>
   <BlazorEnableTimeZoneSupport>false</BlazorEnableTimeZoneSupport>
   <BlazorWebAssemblyPreserveCollationData>false</BlazorWebAssemblyPreserveCollationData>
  ```
- Making sure I have the .NET WebAssembly tools installed
  [image]
- Making sure I'm not using any unncessary nuget packages

But still the download size is very large
[image]

When switching to Brotli compression ([using the web.config provided by microsoft](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/main/aspnetcore/blazor/host-and-deploy/webassembly/_samples/web.config)) the .dlls are smaller in size, but the .js and .css are not compressed any more. How do I work around this?

[image]

Is there something else I can do, am I missing something?
Thank you!

Comment: Are you using the entirety of Telerik? If not, write your own components to reduce download size. Currently Telerik is your biggest package. I've written custom Blazor frameworks that does everything a modern web application needs, and it doesn't even reach 500kb. Alternatively, check if you can get a Telerik package that only includes what you need to run the app.

Comment: I wonder if `UseResponseCompression` will help here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/response-compression?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: @Marius I'm using a lot of components from Telerik, and I have not found a package that only includes what I need. I did find that they support Lazy Loading, but I don't think that will make a difference (because it's still loading the complete dll after all).


In response to UseResponseCompression, it was my understanding that this doesn't work for Blazor WASM (when trying to add it, I even get the error message that it's not found).